# How do I order multiple custom post types in the same menu position ( menu_position = 20 - below Pages)?

Tags: custom-post-types

These are the args I used to get "Artists" display above "Master Artist Lookup"  using the "menu_position" parameter. However , still does not display in menu correctly

```
        $args = [
            'label'              => __('Artists', SMF_CORE_NAME),
            'labels'             => [
                'name'          => __('Artists', SMF_CORE_NAME),
                'singular_name' => __('Artist'),
                'add_new_item'  => __('Add New Artist', SMF_CORE_NAME),
                'add_new'       => __('Add New Artist', SMF_CORE_NAME),
                'new_item'      => __('Add New Artist', SMF_CORE_NAME),
                'all_items'     => __('All Artists', SMF_CORE_NAME),
                'edit_item'     => __('Edit Artist', SMF_CORE_NAME)
            ],
            'supports'           => ['title', 'thumbnail'],
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'public'             => true,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-format-audio',
            'can_export'         => true,
            'has_archive'        => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => false,
            'menu_position' => '20.1',
        ];


$args = [
    'label'              => __('Master Artist Lookup', SMF_CORE_NAME),
    'labels'             => [
        'name'          => __('Master Artist Lookup', SMF_CORE_NAME),
        'singular_name' => __('Master Artist Lookup'),
        'add_new_item'  => __('Add New Artist', SMF_CORE_NAME),
        'add_new'       => __('Add New Artist', SMF_CORE_NAME),
        'new_item'      => __('Add New Artist', SMF_CORE_NAME),
        'all_items'     => __('All Artists', SMF_CORE_NAME),
        'edit_item'     => __('Edit Artist', SMF_CORE_NAME)
    ],
    'supports'           => ['title', 'thumbnail'],
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'public'             => true,
    'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-format-audio',
    'can_export'         => true,
    'has_archive'        => false,
    'publicly_queryable' => false,
    'menu_position' => '20.2',
        ];
```

Comment: This has frustrated me for ages and all the documentation I've read in the codex and on other similar questions produces mixed results.  It's super frustrating.  I've used the decimal method but in quite a few instances have just left things as 'this is the best I'm going to get'.  Would love to see some answers to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to affect where CPTs appear in the admin menu: using `menu_position` and controlling when the CPTs are registered.

Using decimal numbers hasn't been reliable in my experience; using an integer like `21`, `22`, etc. has been more effective. If you have so many CPTs there aren't enough integers, the other trick is to register the one you want first first, then register the second, then register the third. By controlling the code order, and keeping the `menu_position` the same for all of them, WP will put them in the order you register them in.

Comment: non-integer solved. thanks!